# Constraints for Stack View in Stack View

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

Why is this happening?

[image]

This is my constraints:

[image]

Two stack views: horizontal and vertical, both distribution set on "Fill Equally".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distribution` property determines the size of the subviews along the stack view axis, in this case, `.fillEqually` on your vertical stack views will cause the switch and label to have the same height.

The `alignment` property will determine the position and size of the views in the other axis. If set to `.fill`, the default value, the view will have the same size as the stack view.

In this case, the stack view will assign a width to the switch and label as wide as the containing stack view, but switches have a fixed size, so they'll override that and remain a fixed width.

If you want the labels and switches to be centered, set `alignment` to `.center`.

Answer (score 2):

Your Vertical StackViews should be set to:

```
Alignment: Center
Distribution: Fill
```

And your Horizontal StackView should be set to:

```
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: Fill Equally
```

Result:

[image]

[image]